# Gray polygon appears in render/camera view but not user perspective

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm working on an assignment for an animation class and there is a gray polygon appearing in my camera persp view and in my renders and I cannot figure out what is causing it.

Here is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27989

[image: Camera perspective, gray polygon present]

[image: User perspective, no gray polygon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grey 'polygon' you see is the background colour. What is happening is your camera clipping end distance is set too low. So any geometry beyond the clip distance is not rendered. Resulting in what you see above.

To fix, simply select the camera and set the Clip distance to a higher value.

Comment: If this happens when navigating in viewport (Not in camera mode or render) then you have to change the clipping in the viewport options (hit "n" to open up the options and change end clipping under "view").